# Kafka Shared State Store Between Kafka DSL KStream Transformers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology where I use Transformer for aggregation of my objects, later down in my topology, I'm trying to read from the State Store that was used in the first Transformer.  It doesn't seem possible to access the data. Is it because state stores are on different partitions?

My topology looks something like this:

```
streamsBuilder.stream("input")
    .transform(new TransformerSupplier1(), "my-store")
    .leftJoin(someKTable, myValueJoiner())
    .flatTransform(new TransformerSupplier2(), "my-store")
```

In my `TransformerSupplier1`'s `Transformer`, my state store is of type `<String, Map<String, Object>>`

In my `TransformerSupplier2`'s `Transformer`, I'm trying to get the state store by the key I used to store in the first transformer but I get null and when I do `.all().peekNextKey()`, nothing is found.

Let me know if I need to put more information for my Transformers and I'll try to obfuscate the real logic. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the output of `Topology#describe()`? This should actually work as expected.

Comment: Hi Will, could you make it work? I'm trying to do exactly the same with `context.getStateStore(my-store)` in both the transformers and the second one being always empty.

Comment: @Rocel for me, it turned out to be that the same keys were being put on different partitions.  I'm using Spring Kafka so not sure if it makes a difference but I had to create a Spring Bean that returns the KTable with the transformer applied and then do the left join after the beans initialized